# Getting error 800a03ec while opening an Excel file

Tags: vbscript

I have written following code to convert XLSX file to CSV format:

```
If WScript.Arguments.Count < 2 Then
    WScript.Echo "Error! Please specify the source path and the destination. Usage: XlsToCsv SourcePath.xls Destination.csv"
    Wscript.Quit
End If

Dim oExcel
Set oExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
Dim oBook
Set oBook = oExcel.Workbooks.Open(Wscript.Arguments.Item(0))
oBook.SaveAs WScript.Arguments.Item(1), 6
oBook.Close False
oExcel.Quit
```

It was working fine when I was giving server path for XLSX file. But, when I am giving local machine path, it is giving me following error:

> File could not be found. Check the spelling of the file name, and verify that file location is correct. If you are trying to open the file from list of most recently used files, make sure that file has not been renamed, moved or deleted
>   code: 800A03EC
>   Source: Microsoft Office Excel

Comment: Please take a look at the preview before you submit a question or an answer.

Comment: What do you call "server path" and "local machine path"? Please show us your command line.

Comment: I have exactly the same problem with MS Office Professional Plus 2010

Answer (score 5):

In case anyone with a similar problem finds this, the error code seems to be a general Excel error which means that it could not open the file.

In my case I tried opening the same file manually and found that Excel wanted to repair a corrupted file. I had been allowed to save it with incorrect validations, but it wouldn't open programmatically. Opening it by hand meant that it could show me a dialog asking whether I wanted to fix it or not.

Comment: Thanks, in my case it was invalid characters in a file name.

Answer (score 4):

If you are still getting this error, I would do a simple echo on both your arguments to make sure they are doing exactly what they should be doing

```
wscript.echo "Arg(0): " & WScript.Arguments.Item(0) & " Arg(1): " & WScript.Arguments.Item(1)
```

Also if you are using cscript.exe to run it, it will by default be looking for  the files in c:\windows\system32\ directory

Comment: And how to modify this default location? also when I copied the file to this location I got exactly the same error:D

Answer (score 0):

In my case the corresponding message is "Unable to set the PaperSize property of the PageSetup class". That occurs when the standard printer is not capable of the page format of the Excel workbook/sheet.